# When can string cause errors analogous to NullPointerException or ArrayOutOfBound index in c++?

Tags: c++, string

Java identifies aforementioned errors i.e. `NullPointerException` and `ArrayOutOfBound` errors unlike C++(g++). How and when can `std::string` in C++ cause these errors?
In what way are these errors handled by C++ (e.g. runtime error, as in JAVA)?

Comment: A C++ program cannot, of course, trigger errors that Java defines. I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I don't find the question hard to understand. The OP assumes a certain amount of common sense on the part of the reader.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes,that I know. I wanted to know in what ways can  aforementioned errors occur in c++ `std::string`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ collections offer the `at` method for checked indexing, guaranteed to throw for out-of-range indices.

Ordinary `[]` indexing is not guaranteed to throw, just giving Undefined Behavior for out-of-range indices, but with an implementation that supports index checking it can be more convenient for debugging and testing.

Correspondingly, C++ has no guaranteed core language supplied checking of nullpointers. Dereferencing a nullpointer just has Undefined Behavior, except in a `typeid` expression. This is because a main principle of the design of C++ is that you should not pay for what you don't use, and ordinarily in C++ one wants the code to run at full throttle without costly checking.

There is no “`string` function” in C++, but there is a `std::string` type supplied by the standard library.

It's possible to initialize a `std::string` with a nullpointer as argument, yielding Undefined Behavior. That is, there is no guaranteed nullpointer check even here. As opposed to core language provided checking, this is arguably a design error, of the oversight kind: it just does not make sense.

Comment: There are loads of places where you must not lie by giving for example a nullpointer instead of a string, a pointer to an element, a pointer into an array or whatever you are contracted to provide. You might want to add why the std::string ctor for a cstring is a special-case.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. -Alf Thanks. Could you please state any simple instance,apart from the one where string is initialized to null, where std::string operation can generate errors same as `NullPointerException` and `ArrayOutOfBound` in coding.

Comment: @KomalJoshi: One case is mentioned in the first sentence of the answer. Initializing a `std::string` with a nullpointer is not such a case (unfortunately). It's just UB.